# Filter a list from another list to retrieve common objects

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a List of Object with the following Model structure:

```
export class Animal{
  public aniId: number;
  public aniName: string;
}

export Class Zoo{
 public id: number;
 public name:string;
 public aniId: number;
}
```

I have a list of a `Zoo` object which contains an `Id for Animal object` as shown below.

[{
        "id": 4343,
        "name": "Canada",
        "aniId": 1000
    },
    {
        "id": 12121,
        "name": "China",
        "aniId": 78
    },
    {
        "id": 4143,
        "name": "Russia",
        "aniId": 58
    }
 ]
My question : If I have a list of Animal Objects, How can I retrieve the list of corresponding Zoos that contains the Animal.

Ex: If I send a List of Animals which will contain animals of Ids 1000 and 58, I should get a list of Zoos of Ids 4343 and 4143

Note: I tried using filter, but i was not able to get the output.

```
allZoo = this.zooList.filter(x=> x.aniId === this.animalList); <-- Issue here
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it work, you can change your filter logic as below

```
allZoo = this.zooList.filter(x => this.animalList.find(animal => animal.aniId === x.aniId) != null)
```

What it does is that it tries to find the animal from `animalList` which matches the `aniId` of the animal from `zooList`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
export class Animal{
   aniId: number;
   aniName: string;
}

export class Zoo{
 public id: number;
 public name:string;
 public aniId: number;
}


let myZoo:Array<Zoo> =[{ "id": 4343, "name": "Canada", "aniId": 1000 }, { "id": 12121, "name": "China", "aniId": 78 }, { "id": 4143, "name": "Russia", "aniId": 58 } ] ;

let myAnimal:Array<Animal> =[{"aniId":1000,"aniName":"ani1"}];

let myZooList:Array<Zoo> = myZoo.filter(x => myAnimal.filter(y=> y.aniId===x.aniId).length>0);

console.log(myZooList);
```